# How to install dependencies when using "R CMD INSTALL" to install R packages?

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I'm developing my first R package (using R 2.13, Ubuntu 10.10).  Let's call it *foo* and let's say that the code in the R/ directory begins with the line `library(bar)`, where *bar* is an existing package in CRAN, on which *foo* depends. My DESCRIPTION file contains the line:

```
Depends: bar
```

When package *foo* is ready for testing, I install it locally using:

```
R CMD INSTALL foo_1.0.tar.gz
```

However, if *bar* is not installed, I see:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘bar’ is not available for package ‘foo’
```

Obviously, if my *foo* were installed from CRAN using `install.packages()`, *bar* would be installed at the same time.  So my question is: how can I ensure that CRAN package *bar* is installed, if required, when I install my package *foo* using `R CMD INSTALL`?  Is this a job for a configuration script?

Comment: Please note that this question is from 2011. Package development is much easier now thanks to RStudio, I would not need to ask this question today.

Comment: No, you still would need to ask this question today.  Not everyone wants to be tied to RStudio.  `R CMD INSTALL` should work out of the box like `install.packages()` does.  Just another shortcoming of R

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually, re-reading the R extensions guide, it doesn't say that `R CMD INSTALL` will get dependencies from CRAN. The `install.packages()` method from within R will do that, but at first glance I don't think `R CMD INSTALL` does.

You can use `install.packages` to install from a .tar.gz, but you have to set `repos=NULL`, and then this applies:

```
 dependencies: logical indicating to also install uninstalled packages
          on which these packages depend/suggest/import (and so on
          recursively).  Not used if repos = NULL.
```

I suspect the thing to do is to get the dependencies out of the DESCRIPTION file and then run R and do an `install.packages()` on those when you are testing your build in a clean environment.

Comment: Yes, my understanding is that DESCRIPTION declares the dependencies, but doesn't install them. And the problem with setting repos=NULL for the tarball is that dependency packages then won't be fetched from CRAN. I'm trying to put myself in the shoes of a user who downloads and installs my tarball; should they be expected to read documentation and error messages or is there a solution?

Comment: The solution is for you to put your package on CRAN and then have the user do install.packages and get the dependencies. I guess there may be some reason why you can't do this. Installing from tarballs isn't a 'simple user' operation, so they're not spoonfed, and should be able to read error messages and your documentation.

Comment: Right. I guess when testing locally, I know that I have the dependencies and if it goes to CRAN, CRAN takes care of the dependencies, so really there isn't a problem :)

Answer (score 19):

Fortunately [Devtools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/index.html) provides an easy solution: `install_deps()`

> install_deps(pkg = ".", dependencies = logical, threads = getOption("Ncpus",1))
>
> Arguments:
>   pkg: package description, can be path or package name.  See
>             ‘as.package’ for more information
>
> dependencies: ‘logical’ indicating to also install uninstalled packages
>             which this ‘pkg’ depends on/links to/suggests. See argument
>             ‘dependencies’ of ‘install.packages’.
>
> threads: number of concurrent threads to use for installing
>             dependencies. It defaults to the option ‘"Ncpus"’ or ‘1’ if
>             unset.

Examples:

```
install_deps(".")  
install_deps("/path/to/package",dependencies="logical")
```

Comment: thanks; this was a "pre-devtools" question, but life is much easier now

Comment: This works on a directory with a package you want to install, but not with a `.tar.gz` file. Effectively, you cannot pass the path to a `.tar.gz` file to `install_deps` in order to install the dependencies, before actually installing the `.tar.gz` file itself.

Comment: @esilva I will if I believe it is correct. But please see comment by Paul Hiemstra.

Answer (score 9):

Similar to @Jonathan Le, but better for script usage :

```
sudo R --vanilla -e 'install.packages("forecast", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")'
```

Comment: What's the usage of  `-e` in your answer?

Comment: Still better: `sudo Rscript -e ...`

Comment: Same but with different quotes, I had a problem with escaping 
 `R --vanilla -e "install.packages('PMA', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')"`

Comment: @alephreish Could you elaborate on why `Rscript -e` is favorable to `R --vanilla -e`?

Comment: @PålBjartan It's cleaner - Rscript is designed for running script while R is primarily a console. Even `R --quiet` still echos the entered commands.

Answer (score 8):

I ended up just using a bash here-document and specifying the cloud mirror to find the dependencies:

```
sudo R --vanilla <<EOF
install.packages('forecast', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
q()
EOF
```

the R package is "forecast", the cloud mirror I used was http://cran.us.r-project.org.  If you want to use a different mirror, here they all are: https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html

The above worked for me in getting R packages into an AWS EMR bootstrap shell script.

Answer (score 8):

Update; as of Feb 2021, the [remotes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/remotes/index.html) package does the trick and has a much smaller footprint than [devtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/index.html):

```sh
R -e "install.packages('remotes')"
R -e "remotes::install_local('/path/to/mypackage.tar.gz', dependencies=T)"
```

Comment: It's not just that `remotes` has a smaller footprint than `devtools`: `devtools` will not install the dependencies of a `.tar.gz` package. This is the only solution that does not require putting the package on CRAN (or "manually" installing the dependencies as in @Spacedman ' s answer).

Answer (score 0):

Following Romain Rossi's idea, here is a simple shell script which installs every argument you send it's way (assuming it's a package):

```
#!/bin/sh 
for f in $* 
    do 
    sudo R --vanilla -e "install.packages('"$f"', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')" 
done
```

Answer (score -2):

The mechanism to do this is to add an entry in the `depends` field in your `DESCRIPTION` file.

```
Depends: bar
```

This will load the `bar` library if already installed, otherwise will install it from CRAN.

This is described in section 1.1.1 of the `Writing R extensions` manual: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file

Comment: I have the Depends field in DESCRIPTION, but bar is not installed from CRAN when I try to install foo.

Comment: It can't.  But if and when *your* package foo is on CRAN *and* a user selects it, she weill also get bar.  Alternatively, you could create a local repo and put both bar and foo in, and then get the same behaviour.