# install.packages() ignoring option to convert warning to error?

Tags: r, cran, install.packages

I'm trying to find a simple way to make `install.packages()` throw an error if it fails (rather than just a warning).

#### What I've tried

Setting [`options(warn=2)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8217926/5783745) converts warnings into errors. Example:

```r
options(warn=2)
warning()
# Error: (converted from warning)
```

I expected this would now error:

```r
install.packages('thispackagedoesntexist')
# Warning in install.packages :
#   package ‘thispackagedoesntexist’ is not available for this version of R
#
# A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
# see the ideas at
# https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

yet it still just gives a warning (no error).

#### Question

How can install.packages() be made to error (rather than simply warn) on any sort of failure?

---

Note:

- There are a few nice ways of making install.packages() [error instead of warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45289764/install-r-packages-using-docker-file), but I'm scouting for something much more lightweight, preferably without installing other packages, which `options()` would achieve nicely (if I can get it working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an RStudio "feature".

First I wondered why the warning isn't printed in red. Then I looked at `install.packages` (in RStudio) and saw this:

```
> install.packages
function (...) 
.rs.callAs(name, hook, original, ...)
<environment: 0x1408432c8>

> getAnywhere(.rs.callAs)
A single object matching ‘.rs.callAs’ was found
It was found in the following places
  tools:rstudio
with value

function (name, f, ...) 
{
    withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(f(...), error = function(e) {
        cat("Error in ", name, " : ", e$message, "\n", sep = "")
    }), warning = function(w) {
        if (getOption("warn") >= 0) 
            cat("Warning in ", name, " :\n  ", w$message, "\n", 
                sep = "")
        invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
    })
}
<environment: 0x1181b4928>
```

See how warnings are handled and how the printed "warning"  isn't actually a warning but `cat` output?

If I run your code in Rgui, I see this:

```
> options(warn=2)
> install.packages('thispackagedoesntexist')
Error: (converted from warning) package ‘thispackagedoesntexist’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

So, I suggest you go to the RStudio developers and complain that they use `cat` to misleadingly print "errors" and "warnings".

You can avoid RStudio's masking of `install.packages` the usual way:

```
> options(warn=2)
> utils::install.packages('thispackagedoesntexist')
Error: (converted from warning) package ‘thispackagedoesntexist’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```